# Javascript check every char in a string and return array element on corresponding position

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, loops

Got a string that is a series of 0 or 1 bit and an array of values, if in the string are characters that are set to 1, I need to return the corresponding value from the array.
example: mystring = "0101"; myarray =["A","B","C","D"]; then result = "B,D"
how can I get this result?

```
  for(var i=0;i<mystring.length;i++){
    if(mystring[i] != 0)
 {
 result = myarray[i];
 }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to work just fine, so you can just add another array and push the values on to that:

```
var result = [];
for (var i = 0 ...
    result.push(myarray[i]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/syA2c/

---

A more clever way to do this would be to apply a filter to `myarray` that checks the corresponding `mystring` index.

```
myarray.filter(function (_, idx) {
    return +mystring[idx];
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/syA2c/1/

Comment: Nice use of filter. To get the result as a string, follow it up with myarray.join(','). http://jsfiddle.net/rviscomi/syA2c/3/

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the characters in the binary string, if you encounter a 1, add the value at the corresponding index in the array to a temporary array. Join the temporary array by commas to get the output string.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure if this is what you are looking for, but this returns the array of matches.

```
   var result = [];
   for(var i=0;i<mystring.length;i++){
       if(parseInt(mystring[i]) !== 0 ) {
          result.push(myarray[i]);
       }
   }
   return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

result = new Array(); 
   for(var i=0;i